# Firebase query using a list of ids (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geofire

I have an `NSArray` containing multiple ids. Is there a way in `Firebase` where I can get all the object with the ids in the array?

I am building a restaurant rating app which uses `GeoFire` to retrieve nearby restaurants. My problem is that `GeoFire` only returns a list of ids of restaurant that are nearby. Is there any way i can query for all the object with the ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do a batch query like that in Firebase.

You will need to loop over your restaurant IDs and query each one using `observeSingleEvent`. For instance:

```
let restaurantIDs: NSArray = ...
let db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
for id in restaurantIDs as! [String] {
    db.child("Restaurants").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot) in
        let restaurant = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        // Process restaurant...
    }
}
```

If you are worried about performance, Firebase *might* be able to group all these `observeSingleEvent` calls and send them as a batch to the server, which may answer your original question after all ;-)

Comment: There is no way to combine these calls, not is one needed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer is considered accepted but I have had really good success using promise kit with the method frank posted with his javascript link [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) and just wanted to share the swift version

So I have a list of users ids that are attached to a post like this: 
also these methods are in my post class where I have access to the post id from firebase

```
// this gets the list of ids for the users to fetch ["userid1", "userid2"....]



func getParticipantsIds() -> Promise<[String]> {

    return Promise { response in
        let participants = ref?.child(self.key!).child("people")
        participants?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let snapshotIds = snapshot.value as? [String] else {
                response.reject(FirebaseError.noData)
                return
            }
            response.fulfill(snapshotIds)
        })

    }
}




// this is the individual query to fetch the userid


 private func getUserById(id:String) -> Promise<UserData> {
       return Promise { response in

           let userById = dbRef?.child("users").child(id)
           userById?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
               guard let value = snapshot.value else {
                   response.reject(FirebaseError.noData)
                   return
               }
               do {
                   let userData = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: value)
                   response.fulfill(userData)
               } catch let error {
                   response.reject(error)
               }
           })

       }
   }


// this is the where the magic happens


func getPostUsers(compeltion: @escaping (_ users:[UserData], _ error:Error?) -> ()){

    getParticipantsIds().thenMap { (id) in
        return self.getUserById(id: id)
    }.done { (users) in
        compeltion(users, nil)
    }.catch({ error in
        compeltion([], error)
    })

}
```

Comment: Have had good success taking this approach with `RxSwift` using the `zip` operator.  Was then able to denormalize my data as suggested by Firebase in the docs.